# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros mediante método post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Necesito hacer una solicitud mediante un método POST a un servidor para obtener un JWT pasando los siguientes parámetros a esta  URL = https://unsitio/web/token

```
Grant Type = zzzzz
Authorization Grants = xxxxxx
Client Id = nnnnnnnn
Client Secret = [Vacio]
Scope = [Vacio]
Username = hhhhhh@vvvv.ggg.oooo.lll
Password = sssssssss
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: puedes revisar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp o https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255725/webrequest-equivalent-to-curl-command . Saludos

Answer (score 0):

seria algo asi como en este ejemplo, solo tienes que cambiar por el valor de tus variables

```
  public async Task<string> ObtenerAutentificacionPost()
        {
            cadenaToken = string.Empty;
            Token token = new Token();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(EngineData.application_json));
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Valor.UrlAutentificacion());
            var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EngineData.clienteID,Valor.Client_Id()));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EngineData.grantType,Valor.Grant_Type()));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EngineData.userName, Valor.Username()));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EngineData.passWord, Valor.Password()));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EngineData.scoPe, Valor.Scope()));
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                cadenaToken = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }
            else
            {
                cadenaToken= EngineData.falso;
            }

            return cadenaToken;
        }
```